# Restkit requestMapping serializing other attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

My implementation is sending some parameters I don't want. Here is the `requestDescriptor`:

```
RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"nombres", @"telefono", @"direccion", @"email", @"identificacion", @"tipo_id", @"recibir_sms_ordenes", @"recibir_correos_ordenes"]];
RKRequestDescriptor *descriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping objectClass:[RKUser class] rootKeyPath:@"me" method:RKRequestMethodAny];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:descriptor];
```

This is the POST request:

```
RKUser *user = [self currentUser].user;     // [self currentUser].user returns the current RKUser
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[manager postObject:user path:@"/api/me.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
  NSLog(@"%@ %@", operation, mappingResult);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"%@ %@", error, operation);
}];
```

In the server, I am getting correctly these attributes (JSON payload) under the key `me`, but I'm also receiving exactly the same attributes under the key `current_user`. This is the JSON payload the server receives:

```
{
    "me": {
        "identificacion": "1104680135",
        "telefono": "123",
        "direccion": "Av.ManuelAgustínAguirreyJoséPicoita",
        "recibir_correos_ordenes": true,
        "email": "admin@macool.me",
        "nombres": "MarioAndres",
        "recibir_sms_ordenes": true,
        "tipo_id": "Cédula"
    },
    "current_user": {
        "me": {
            "identificacion": "1104680135",
            "telefono": "123",
            "direccion": "Av.ManuelAgustínAguirreyJoséPicoita",
            "recibir_correos_ordenes": true,
            "email": "admin@macool.me",
            "nombres": "MarioAndres",
            "recibir_sms_ordenes": true,
            "tipo_id": "Cédula"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I send duplicate data under the key `current_user`. How do I avoid this? Is this a bug?

I am using Restkit 0.22.0 pulled from its github repository (currently commit *232f7f0*)

Comment: Do you have a mapping somewhere that has `current_user` in it? Is `current_user` a relationship on `RKUser` entity?

Comment: I don't have any mapping with `current_user` and `current_user` isn't a relationship. Seems like a bug

Comment: I've never seen RestKit just make up a set of content. It looks like another request descriptor is matching the class and adding another root of content...